# Range values in max-len

Tags: eslint

Is it possible to define multiple values for max-len?

I want to make 80 chars as a warning and 100 as error.

Something like the code below (which doesn't work):

```
"max-len": [1, 80, 4, {"ignoreComments": true}],
"max-len": [2, 100, 4, {"ignoreComments": true}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is not available. 
In general in Eslint, options for a rule never determine the severity (error or warning) of the rule.